# No Data Available in Game Center with iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, game-center

I'm trying to make a game using Game Center and Swift with iOS. However, whenever I display my leaderboard, I'm getting a screen that says, "No Data Available." Also, my NSLogs say that the application is not recognized by Game Center. I had found online that I'm supposed to add my Game Center leaderboard ID in an asset info field, but I can't find it. Does anyone know how I can fix my problem?

Comment: You have to add your app to iTunes Connect, enable Game Center there and add your leaderboard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've done this, but I'm only testing the app right now. How do I get my scores to show up in an Ad Hoc distribution?

Comment: Enable Game Center for the new version of your app in iTC. That should fix the problem with your app not being recognized by Game Center.

Comment: It's enabled in both iTunes Connect and Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! All I had to do was change the bundle identifier from com.example... to the bundle ID used on iTunes Connect and now it works!

Comment: Not sure why someone gave you -1, but you are now back at 0. This was my issue.  Unity had truncated the bundle id.  Thank you!